# Как лучше очистить память занимаемую переменной?

Tags: php

Скрипт на php работает 10 минут. В самом начале получает в переменную `$var` большой массив, который вскоре становится не нужным, возникает идея удалить его что бы не занимал память. Как это лучше сделать?
`unset($var)` или `$var = null` и стоит ли это делать в описанной ситуации?

Comment: память все равно освободится, когда сборщик мусора пожелает, а не когда вы сделаете `unset` или присвоите `null`, Разница между этими вариантами не велика, только `unset` еще саму переменную  из списка переменных удаляет, поэтому она становится снова необъявленной. Ну и собственно есть разное поведение `unset` в зависимости от типа аргумента, что в целом описано в справке по использованию.

Comment: Сборщик мусора ни разу не сработает за время работы скрипта в 10 минут? А если переменная удалена, то сборщик наверное полюбому должен сработать и удалить её...

Comment: сборщик то может и сработает (если памяти будет не хватать), но время его срабатывания мало будет зависеть, от того каким способом вы освободили данные. То есть установка переменной в `null` или `unset` сборщик мусора не запускает. Он своей жизнью живет.

Comment: На самом деле, стоит разобраться в двух других вещах. 1) Нужно ли передавать в переменную $var такой большой массив, 2) Почему скрипт работает так долго?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитайте статью https://habrahabr.ru/post/134784/  там всё подробно разбирается. Если кратко - используйте unset()